# How do I delete a specific Jfrog build with the cli (and its corresponding artifact)

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'm confused about how to perform this operation, it almost seems like it's not supported. Looking at the docs I see no examples for deleting a specific build version: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/discarding-old-builds-from-artifactory

I use build discarding now, but that's not what this is. I want to remove a specific build version and its corresponding artifact, not use `--max-days` or `--max-builds`. How is this possible? I want to delete the build AND the artifact.

I use Jfrog to host an internal helm repo, helm has no built-in command to delete a chart from a remote repo.

Answer (score 1):

For deleting a specific artifact of a build using jfrog cli run

```bash
jfrog rt delete --build build-name/build-number
```

Parse `--dry-run` to know which artifacts would have been deleted.

More info on [CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DeletingFile](https://docs.jfrog-applications.jfrog.io/jfrog-applications/jfrog-cli/cli-for-jfrog-artifactory#deleting-files).

Comment: I am not trying to delete docker or helm bundle, I am trying to delete release bundle